# Using a function from a different class?

Tags: python

I am learning python and coming from a java/kotlin background i am tryin to figure out how to use a class defined in another file invoke the functions inside it?

Here is my class:

```
class Practise:
    def messageFunction(message):
        print("your message you entered is " + message)
        return

    def messageFunction2(message):
        print("mesage 2 " + message)
        return

    def messageFunction3(message):
        print("message 3  " + message)
        return
```

Here is the main python file i want to invoke the functions inside the class above(that is on a seperate file)

```
from practise import Practise

practise = practise.Practise()

practise.messageFunction("wagwan")
```

I get this error:

```
File "/home/me/Work/PycharmProjects/practise/venv/Main.py", line 3, in <module>
    practise = Practise()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`
```

Comment: Is the file that contains `Practise` called `Practise`? If that's the case, then try: `from Practise import Practise`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41276067/importing-class-from-another-file

Does this help?

Comment: As an aside - in Python classes are typically used to create instances of an object with different state. Although classes can be used to group together functions it is more typical to just define those functions in  a module and let the module be the *grouping* mechanism.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using class/function in another module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27995900/using-class-function-in-another-module)

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Python version 3.8. `from Temp import Temp; t = Temp()` --> `<Temp.Temp object at 0x0000025ED1F88760>`

Comment: Could you please share the file structure showing the names of the folder and files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the way you're importing the other module. You should do something like the following

```
import <modulename>

practise = <modulename>.Practise()

practise.messageFunction("wagwan")
```

Or

```
from <modulename> import Practise

practise = Practise()

practise.messageFunction("wagwan")
```

where `<modulename>` is the name of the file you define the class over.

Comment: That did not work. still getting the same error. the Practise class is inside Practise.py

Comment: use [snake_case](https://namingconvention.org/python/module-naming.html) for module names (file name). That should resolve the conflict

Comment: so in this case, rename your file `practise.py` and `from practise import Practise`

Comment: nope that did not work, same error. renamed both files to lowercase.

Comment: from practise import Practise

practise = practise.Practise()

practise.messageFunction("wagwan")

Comment: since you're using the `from .. `  syntax,  let the second line be "`practise = Practise()`" (without "`practice.`")

Comment: Am getting this error now 

  File "/home/jonathanrichards/Work/PycharmProjects/practise/venv/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    practise.messageFunction("wagwan")
TypeError: messageFunction() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

even though i supplied one arg only?

Comment: Oh the import has worked okay now.. this is another issue. to solve it, add "`self`" as first parameter to the methods inside the class. like this `messageFunction3(self, message)`